# Linear Maps, Vector Spaces, Bijectivity

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $S, T ∈ Lin(V, V)$. Prove: If there exists a nonzero vector $x$ such that $STx = 0$ then there exists a nonzer vector
$y$ such that $TSy = 0$.

My question is, since there is a theorem saying that if you have a mapping $T→V$ such that the $dim(T)=dim(V)$ then the mapping is bijective, which implies a trivial kernel, so how can there be a non-zero vector that is mapped by the bijective function $S$ to $0$?

Comment: in the statement above isn't assuming neither $T$ nor $S$ are bijective

Comment: As i said the theorem states that a mapping from dimension n to dimension n (V to V) is bijective?

Comment: there are bijective mappings, yes, but  in your statement: *If there exists a nonzero vector x such that STx = θ then there exists a nonzero vector y such that TSy = θ*, isn't that hypothesis.

Comment: Oh i see, so these mappings are not bijective or injective. So then how does this relate to finding a y such that TS(y) = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the rank-nullity theorem states that for $T\in L(V,V)$, we have 
$$\begin{align}
\dim(V)&=\dim\mathscr R(T)+\dim\mathscr N(T) \\
&=\text{rank}(T)+\text{nullity}(T)
\end{align}$$
so you'd have $\text{nullity}(T)=0$ whenever $T$ is an **onto** mapping, i.e. $\mathscr R(T)=V$. This must be the source of your confusion.

Since there exist $x\in V$ such that $x\ne 0$ and $STx=0$, we have $Tx\in\mathscr N(S)$.

If $\mathscr N(S)={0}$ then $S$ is surjective by the above theorem and that $\exists y\in V$ such that $Sy=x$, therefore $TSy=Tx=0$.

If $\mathscr N(S)\ne {0}$, there exist $y\in V$ such that $Sy=0$ so $TSy=T0=0$ in this case also.

Comment: @janmarqz The original question (before being edited) stated something along the line of "If $T\in L(V,V)$, then $T$ is injective" so I thought that the OP must have misunderstood the statement of rank-nulity theorem so I wanted to clarify it.

Comment: i saw nothing :P